# d3.js remove axis tick transition

Tags: d3.js

It appears that the ticks in axes have some sort of default transitions when zoomed or panned: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/svg/axis.js

My zooming panning behavior is like in this example (except that for some reason, the transitions are much more obvious in my code, which has larger font sizes):
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4015254

I would like to remove or overwrite the axis tick transitions for performance reasons. How do I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The example you've linked to doesn't have any ticks.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, you're right, it doesn't have downward tick lines, but it does have a tick group, which contains gridlines and the date labels. If there were tick lines, they would also be inside this group. By looking in the [source](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/svg/axis.js), it appears that anything with a class of "tick" gets a transition on it, and that's what I'm trying to remove. Sorry for the unclear example.

Comment: It sounds to me like your only option would be to modify the source.